# Jquery validation result through javascript. Not a button with post back. asp .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

I am trying to fire the jQuery validation on my form when this div is pressed

```
<div onclick="jquery();">Continue</div>
```

Then, in the javacript, I want to call the jquery form validate action.

```
    function jquery() {
        //==--validate inputs--==\\
        var valid = $('#Form').validate();
        alert(valid);
        if (valid) {
            // Do other actions here
        }
        else{//do nothing, form is not ready for other actions}
    }
```

My jQuery file is loaded in a master page, and contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#aspnetForm').validate({

    // Validation Rules
    rules: 
        // Name
        Name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        // Other Rules
    },

    }

    }); // end form.validate
});   // end document.ready
```

I took out some of the rules, so the syntax might be off in the jQuery.
The document ready jquery is running, so I'm pretty sure the jQuery file is fine, I just want to see if all the rules were followed on the javascript function with an if statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well that's a bit dangerous imho to name a function 'jquery', and if it's not dangerous it's at least misleading ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I renamed it for this question. I thought it might help understanding the question. Sorry Paul

Comment: Sweet!!! I found this tutorial and it worked GREAT! http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/jquery-form-validation-example

i had to use validator.form(); Works GREAT!

Comment: Oke, if I may rephrase: the jquery function is fired when you press the Continue div but the validation is not performed? Well... the jquery function refers to: #Form and the validate method to the #apsnetForm id... that's not right.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet!!! I found this tutorial and it worked GREAT!

http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/jquery-form-validation-example

i had to use validator.form(); Works GREAT!